# Should I avoid Shanghai because of air quality problems?

Tags: health, shanghai, air-quality

I have seen a number of reports and pictures of the current problems in Shanghai due to air quality. Is it dangerous enough that I should stay away? I am scheduled to spend three days there teaching a course indoors.

Comment: Except if you have a respiratory medical condition I wouldn't worry too much. Yes, it can be unpleasant, and I can imagine that long-time exposure is really harmful, but going there for three days and being indoors most of the time won't do you any harm. If you're really concerned you can get a [mask](http://aqicn.org/mask/), but make sure it filters PM2.5 particles. Disclaimer: I'm not a doctor, but have been in Beijing for four months with quite some bad air pollution.

Comment: I think this question is related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11698/do-i-need-to-take-any-precautions-regarding-smog-when-travelling

Comment: Just to at to @BartArondson comment. The choice of the mask is really important. Note that surgical masks, like a lot of people wear it, don't have much effect at all, so don't just buy the masks they sell at the supermarket or on the streets. It should specify N95 or N99 or something like that.

Comment: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/315N6NKNSQL._SL500_AA280_.jpg

Comment: Definitely, but if you have business there so don't stay there too long. The air is a huge problem.

Answer (score 14):

TL;DR: I wouldn't cancel a three-day trip because of the current spike.

1. Pollution is like smoking cigarettes: while it's theoretically possible to get lung cancer from a single puff, in practice it's repeated exposure over the years that kills you.  Barring asthma and the like, three days of bad air is unlikely to have any measurable impact on your health (and, unlike ciggies, haze isn't even addictive!).
2. Most larger office buildings, and virtually all larger hotels, have central air conditioning systems that filter the air.  So your exposure indoors will be very limited.
3. Shanghai is by the coast, so pollution comes and goes with the wind.  By the time you get there, you might have blue skies.  (This is not true for China's worst-polluted cities, which are inland.)

Comment: It might affect your sightseeing though, as many of the views will be shrouded. Based on what it's like in Hong Kong at the moment, which is much less affected, night-time sightseeing works best as the lights mostly cut through!

Comment: "Pollution is like smoking cigarettes: while it's theoretically possible to get lung cancer from a single puff, in practice it's repeated exposure over the years that kills you." then how you explain the fact that some smokers never get lung cancer and some non-smokers get lung cancer (and they never smoked)?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch the same reason some sportspeople don't break bones and some people who never do sports do.

Answer (score 4):

Note: This was written in late 2014. Anyone planning a trip to China should check typical conditions via any of the available sites, but I'd imagine that things will not be especially different for some years to come.

Over numerous trips to China I have found that the claims re the effect of air quality seem to  be excessively alarmist. If you are asthmatic or similar it is not liable to cause major problems for a short visit spent mainly indoors. While the worst case conditions can be extremely bad in many Chinese cities I imagine that they are not vastly different than the worst conditions that an asthmatic needs to be prepared for in many locations. ie Not good but also not so unusual that you may not encounter them in many places - which is why asthmatics need to have, and usually do have the knowledge and experience and medication to handle occasional bad events.

[Shanghai real time air pollution monitor results here](http://aqicn.org/city/shanghai/)

Note that these are claimed to be accurate real-time results BUT I have no ideas whether they are in fact "cooked".
They are reporting PM2.5 as the main indicator -  a few days ago they were using PM10. Both are charted. The update time is shown on the webpage.

[image]

PM2.5 is shown here as 159 (ug/m^3) and has had a range of 129-492 in the last 2 days. 
International limits vary by country but 50 to 100 is typically the long term acceptable limit.

I've been in numerous Chinese cities when the air was vastly affected by pollution without being troubled by it at all. Others are less lucky. For a period of only 3 days I'd expect it to not be a major issue.

Answer (score 3):

My 2 yr experience in Shanghai tells me that the air got seriously bad from mid-Nov all the way to May. Only around the summer and fall time the Ocean wind comes in to blow off the bad air.

If you are allergic to any airborne particles, be it dust or mold, and you continue to breathe those PM bad air for awhile, your allergy will get worse.

I used to work in a TB lab where we were using 3M N95 with comfortable fit. I got mine from http://amzn.to/1V9m58V. 3M doesn't sell it in China. Good luck buying it online in China.  I do reuse the mask for multiple time until the belt broke. And by then, the mask looks seriously grey. So the money I spend well-worth it.

Do check out the real-time air pollution map from UC-Berkeley.  Gosh !
http://berkeleyearth.lbl.gov/air-quality/map.php

Not to mention people in Shanghai subway sneeze or cough all the time without covering !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, no doubt about it. If you can, avoid any Chinese urban areas. I live in Hainan (an island in southern China, with the best air quality in the country), the difference is HUGE. Believe me, you don't want to put that shit in your lungs, whatever others less careful about somebody else's health (and probably also their own) say.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add my two cents but I arrived at Shanghai 6 days ago and while my first reaction is *"oh, it stinks so bad!"*, the actual air pollution statistics is not so bad as to consider cancelling your trip, especially a short trip.

In [Air Quality Index](https://aqicn.org/city/shanghai/), Shanghai reaches "Unhealthy" label around noon quite often, but so do all of other Asian cities like Tokyo, Seoul, and Hong Kong, except they are not so bad as Shanghai. If you take Shanghai too seriously shouldn't you also take those cities seriously?

This may not apply if you have some respiratory problems as others mentioned. But for normal people to travel, the air wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: At time of writing, Shangai's PM2.5 reading is 158 ("Unhealthy"), vs 78 in Tokyo, 62 in Seoul and 58 in Hong Kong ("Moderate").  So, yes, Shanghai's air is objectively worse, and it's the "good" season now!

Comment: @jpatokal I did check all of them before posting but all three frequently score unhealthy (in Seoul's case yesterday was pretty bad, for example). Shanghai is the worst, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have asthma and spend plenty of time in China. Sometimes, especially in the winter in North China, the air is horrible (poor people burn coal for heat). Other times, things are ok. The last two years have been somewhat better.

I have found it to be manageable. If you do not have asthma or another respiratory disease, I say "Don't Believe the Hype" and think it should be ok for a small handful of days.